# What time format is the following?

Tags: r, time

I have the following datetime string:

```
mytimestr <- "2014-04-15T14:40:00.000000000+00:00"
```

I assumed it was an ISO3339 format, but the following format string, which should describe that:

```
> as.POSIXct(mytimestr, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E9S%Ez")
[1] NA
```

Produces NA as you can see.  Questions are either:

1. Can you identify a format that decodes this time?  Or
2. Is there a common resource or function that can look at a string time and tell me the time format?

Comment: `nanotime::nanotime("2014-04-15T14:40:00.000000000+00:00")`. The format string you provided is the default in `nanotime`. Although `as.POSIXct` can handle fractional seconds, it can't parse nanosecs.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `ymd_hms` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(mytimestr)
#[1] "2014-04-15 14:40:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that parses it, but what is the format string itself?